# I get the correct view only if I scroll in IOS using Constraint layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, constraints

I have created a view with segment control. So when I select **No** it should show another **set of questions**. I'm achieving this using **tableview** and **constraints**. I'm setting the correct constraints in code as well as in UI but the it shows only when I scroll the UI. This is the code through which I'm setting the constraint

```
- (void)segmentChanged:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isEqual:_TestedForPestiAntiBioticsToggle]) {

        if (_TestedForPestiAntiBioticsToggle.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {



            //_percentOfAntiBodyTxt.hidden=YES;
            //_percentagelbl.hidden=YES;
            _ans3bConstraints.constant = 75;


        }
        else {
            _percentOfAntiBodyTxt.text = @"";
            //_percentOfAntiBodyTxt.hidden=NO;

            //_percentagelbl.hidden=NO;
           _ans3bConstraints.constant = 5;

        }
    }
}
```

The screenshot of the my layout is as follows
[the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJ6Ir.png)

This is the image of my UI
[This is the correct UI I get after scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb6wl.png)
[This is the incorrect UI I get before scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWHA1.png)

I need to get the proper UI without scroll.

Comment: Instead of doing it like this, you can also do it by changing the cell height based on your condition. If it's no height will be requiredHeight + 5 else requiredHeight + 75. Right now, with your case, I believe, you require to reload the particular cell.

Answer (score 1):

I just reloaded my table view and table data and it worked like charm. This is the code:

- (void)segmentChanged:(id)sender
  {
      if ([sender isEqual:_TestedForPestiAntiBioticsToggle]) {

  ```
      if (_TestedForPestiAntiBioticsToggle.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {


           _percentOfAntiBodyTxt.text = @"";
          //_percentOfAntiBodyTxt.hidden=YES;
          //_percentagelbl.hidden=YES;
          _ans3bConstraints.constant = 75;
          [self reloadTable];
          [self.tableView reloadData];

      }
      else {

          //_percentOfAntiBodyTxt.hidden=NO;

          //_percentagelbl.hidden=NO;
         _ans3bConstraints.constant = 5;

          [self reloadTable];
          [self.tableView reloadData];

      }
  }
  ```

  }